# How do I replace a string between a set of delimiter strings including the second delimiter with sed?

Tags: parsing, sed

How do I replace a string between a set of delimiter strings with sed?  The first delimiter is a string which is not replaced while; the second delimiter is a single char but needs to be replaced as part of the replacement.

i.e.

```
FIRST_DELEM="GetVal(" 
SECOND_DELEM=”,”
Example string:
abc = param.GetVal((m_AstringToReplace, xml_SomeData, StringParameter(L""));
```

The String to replace or remove = (m_AstringToReplace,

This following sed command will only parse out the string, it does not replace it.

```
sed -e 's/.*GetVal(\(.*\),.*/\1/'
```

How would I use sed to replace the string using these complex delimiters ?

Answer (score 0):

With this as input:

```
$ cat file
abc = param.GetVal((m_AstringToReplace, xml_SomeData, StringParameter(L""));
```

This performs the replacement of the string that starts immediately following `GetVal(` and ends with the first comma:

```
$ sed -re 's/(GetVal[(])[^,]*,/\1REPLACEMENT/' file
abc = param.GetVal(REPLACEMENT xml_SomeData, StringParameter(L""));
```

The regex `(GetVal[(])` captures the first delimiter into group 1.  `[^,]*,` matches all that follows up to and including the first comma, `,`.

Note that, if we had used `.*,` in place of `[^,]*,`, then we would have matched everything up to the *last* comma in the string.

In the replacement part of the substitution, `\1` restores the first delimiter, the one we wanted to keep.  All that follows is the replacement, whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed !